# Mutate array object at given index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to set a copied array with one object changed with one mutation.

I will explain it in code:

Component has array `v-model` and to modify object at index we have to mutate all the arary:

```
computed: {
    array: {
        get() {
            return this.$store.state.array;
        },
        set(value) {
            this.$store.commit('updateArray', value);
        },
    },
},

onObjectDropped(event) {
    // That will mutate array = setter will be called
    this.array = [...this.array];
    // We take an index of array at which we want to assigne object from 'otherArray'
    this.array[index] = this.otherArray[selectedIndex].elements[elementsIndex]
},
```

I would like to move second line from `onObjectDropped` method and add it into first line where we are creating copy of it to mutate an array only once, cuz the setter will not modifie the array with new value from other array.

Comment: _...I would like to move second line from `onObjectDropped` method and add it into first line..._. And what's the issue?

Comment: Vue doesn't detect changes to the index of an array by default. To do that you'll need to use the [Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) method (which is also aliased at `this.$set` in your context). In your case you could use `this.$set(this.array, index, this.otherArray[selectedIndex].elements[elementsIndex])` instead and Vue will detect the change.